# Doxygen: hide markdown file from related pages

Tags: doxygen

I want to document test cases that consist of multiple files with a separate markdown file:

```
tests/test_a/
             file1
             file2
             test_a.md
```

However, the file `test_a.md` (which includes the Doxygen documentation for the test) now shows up in the 'related pages' tab of Doxygen, which is annoying if you have a lot of tests. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

That's probably exactly what [`EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_patterns) is for:

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS += */tests/*.md
```

*Edit:*
That will exclude all `.md` files somewhere in the `tests/` directory tree from being processed by Doxygen.

*Edit2:*
A **potential workaround** to let Doxygen still process the files but don't let them show up under *"related pages"* would be to explicitly declare them as [subpages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#subpaging) of another page:

```
@subpage tests_testa
```

This, however, requires that the `*.md` file in `test_a` defines a [`page` including the respective identifier](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_page_header), i.e. `{#tests_testa}` with the example above.

Comment: Eh, right. Sorry, didn't understood your question in the way that you still want the content of the md file to be processed by Doxygen. Added that (crucial) note to my answer. Workaround: explicitly declare the `.md` files somewhere as a subpages of other pages.

Comment: I ended up writing a python script to go through the pages html file, remove the unwanted links from the related pages, and rewrite the link table so it looks like it looks nice. It's definitely a hack fix, but it works for my purposes. I don't think it'll work for everyone's setup though :(